# Query Hierarchical Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to profile my data set to find the data discrepancies.

My sample date set:

```
id  status       stdate         enddate
1   new          01-JUL-17  31-JUL-17
1   process      01-OCT-17  31-DEC-18
1   new          01-JAN-19  31-JAN-19--- issue
2   new          01-SEP-14  31-JAN-15
2   process      01-JUN-16  30-NOV-17
2   complete     01-DEC-17  31-DEC-18
....
....
```

I would like to find out how many of those IDs have  a result status that is older than current. The order of the status sequence should be NEW-PROCESS-COMPLETE. So I want report all IDs where the most recent status has reversed to an earlier status.

Comment: OK.  What have you tried?  Take a look at oracle analytic functions and windowing

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: we r using oracle 12c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LAG()` function to find the offending rows, as in:

```
with x (id, status, stdate, enddate, 
        prev_id, prev_status, prev_stdate, prev_enddate) as (
  select
    id, 
    status,
    stdate,
    enddate,
    lag(id) over(partition by id order by stdate),
    lag(status) over(partition by id order by stdate),
    lag(stdate) over(partition by id order by stdate),
    lag(enddate) over(partition by id order by stdate)
  from my_table
)
select * from x
where status = 'new' and prev_status in ('process', 'complete')
   or status = 'process' and prev_status = 'complete'
```

**Note**: I assume you need to compare only between rows of the same `ID`.

Comment: i'm getting "ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function"  also, can we make it more generic to figure a status that has older than current

Comment: @stackuser Fixed it. `LAG()` cannot be directly used in the `WHERE`.

Comment: is possible to define the status order/sequence in the with clause and check where the status has older than current?

Comment: @stackuser Yes, you can create more columns as needed. To do it, you define the name of the new column(s) in the `WITH` clause header, and then add the expression in the `SELECT`. For example you can add and "artificial" `seq` as `row_number() over(partition by id order by stdate)`.

Comment: sorry sir not clear :-( so how do we use this row_number() to fetch all the current statuses that have older statues

Comment: @stackuser I added extra columns that show the previous row. It depends on your strategy: you can retrieve all columns (as in the example), or just the primary key of the table; whichever is easier for you.

Comment: sorry sir i might have not articulating my need here.. My bad.. I have amended my question.  Basically The order of the status sequence is NEW-PROCESS-COMPLETE, so I want to report all Id's where the most recent status has reversed went to earlier?

Comment: @stackuser I think I got the search condition you need, considering all three status. Changed the answer accordingly.